# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level i need an solution

Tags: python

```py
il = true
while il == true:
     Op = input("do you want to register or log in?? L for Log In and R for register")
     print(Op)

     if Op == "R":
          x = 0
       print("Register")
       NU = input("Enter new username")
       print(NU)
       NP = input("Enter new password")
       print(NP)
       Ac = {"Username":NU, "password": NP}
       print(Ac)
       x = x + 1

           elif Op == "L":
                IU = input("Input Username:")
       print(IU)
       IP = input("input your password:")
       print(IP)

        print(x)
         ils = input(s tos stop)
          if ils == "s":
               il = false
```

Solution plz??

Comment: Indentation (the space between the start of the line and the first character) is important in Python. Your indentation is wrong, so it has caused an error. Fix the indentation levels of your code. https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php

Answer (score 0):

The 'elif' statement is wrongly indented

```
 if Op == "R":
   x = 0
   print("Register")
   NU = input("Enter new username")
   print(NU)
   NP = input("Enter new password")
   print(NP)
   Ac = {"Username":NU, "password": NP}
   print(Ac)
   x = x + 1

 elif Op == "L":
   IU = input("Input Username:")
   print(IU)
   IP = input("input your password:")
   print(IP)

   print(x)
   ils = input(s tos stop)
   if ils == "s":
      il = false
```